# macros inside tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I wanted to make a bit more readable the tex code I'm using and, in this respect, I wanted to somehow use a macro for the following code:

```
\draw (10 mm,10 mm) -- (20 mm,10 mm);
```

I've created the following newcommands:

```
\newcommand*\horizontalLineCoor[3]{  \draw (#1 mm,#2 mm) -- (#3 mm,#2 mm);   }
\newcommand*\horizontalLineLength[3]{\draw (#1 mm,#2 mm) -- (#1+#3 mm,#2 mm);}
```

I'm receiving this sort of errors:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `mm' (in '( mm').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.31 \horizontalLineLength(10
                             , 20, 10);
?
```

Can you give me hand with this macros:) Thank you!
R

The test file (this should draw 2 horizontal lines):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcommand*\horizontalLineCoor[3]{  \draw (#1 mm,#2 mm) -- (#3 mm,#2 mm);   }
\newcommand*\horizontalLineLength[3]{\draw (#1 mm,#2 mm) -- (#1+#3 mm,#2 mm);}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  xscale=2,
  yscale=2,
  virtual/.style={thin,dashed}
  ]
\horizontalLineCoor(10, 10, 20);    %%%\draw (10 mm,10 mm) -- (20 mm,10 mm);   
\horizontalLineLength(10, 20, 10);  %%%\draw (10 mm,20 mm) -- (20 mm,20 mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Interesting caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13):

You provided no test file but the error shows you used the syntax

```
\horizontalLineLength(10, 20, 10);
```

But you have defined the command with three TeX arguments, that supplied the `;` so

```
\horizontalLineLength{10}{20}{10}
```

Answer (score 7):

You *can* use the syntax `\horizontalLineCoor(10, 10, 20)` if you prefer. However, this is a bit awkward, because TeX does not treat multiple arguments like C or other programming languages; if you define

```
\newcommand{\foo}[3]{...}
```

the call should be like

```
\foo{x}{y}{z}
```

each argument enclosed in *braces*.

However, the syntax with parentheses can be set up using `xparse`, that provides fairly general methods for inputting arguments.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\NewDocumentCommand{\horizontalLineCoor}{>{\SplitArgument{2}{,}}r()}{%
  \horizontalLineCoorDo#1%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\horizontalLineLength}{>{\SplitArgument{2}{,}}r()}{%
  \horizontalLineLengthDo#1%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\horizontalLineCoorDo}{mmm}{%
  \horizontalLineDo{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\horizontalLineLengthDo}{mmm}{%
  \horizontalLineDo{#1}{#2}{#1+#3}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\horizontalLineDo}{mmm}{%
  \draw (#1 mm,#2 mm) -- (#3 mm,#2 mm)%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  xscale=2,
  yscale=2,
  virtual/.style={thin,dashed}
  ]
\horizontalLineCoor(10, 10, 20);    %%%\draw (10 mm,10 mm) -- (20 mm,10 mm);   
\horizontalLineLength(10, 20, 10);  %%%\draw (10 mm,20 mm) -- (20 mm,20 mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Interesting caption}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The definition

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\horizontalLineCoor}{>{\SplitArgument{2}{,}}r()}{%
  \horizontalLineCoorDo#1%
}
```

says that `\horizontalLineCoor` accepts *one* argument enclosed between parentheses; but we can tell LaTeX to split this argument at commas (there should be two of them), so at the end a call such as

```
\horizontalLineCoor(10, 10, 20)
```

results in

```
\horizontalLineCoorDo{10}{10}{20}
```

so the arguments are “TeX-normalized”. Now it's a matter of defining `\horizontalLineCoorDo`, which I do in an indirect fashion so as to avoid code duplication for the main code, since `\horizontalLineCoor` and `\horizontalLineLength` do very similar tasks.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is just to remark that Ti*k*Z comes with its own means to define such abbreviations. Your commands can be represented by two styles, `horizontal to` and `horizontal add`, which do the same as what your commands should do (if I understand correctly).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  xscale=2,
  yscale=2,
 horizontal to/.style={insert path={coordinate(aux) -- (#1mm,0 |-aux)}},
 horizontal add/.style={insert path={-- ++ (#1mm,0)}}, 
  ]
\draw (10mm,10mm) [horizontal to=20];
\draw (10mm,20mm) [horizontal add=10];
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Interesting caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Eventually, the appropriate TikZ answer! (+1)

Comment: @CarLaTeX I can't guess what you mean, I got a badge for my answer!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle lol